# Why does daes date1.compareTO(date2)==0 even if dates are the same doesnt give me what i want?

Tags: java, android, date

I am writing a reminder app that is supposed to have a hashmap (`Lebanon` in the snippet below) containing different dates as keys and holiday name as value. So this is my calendar:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
        pickerDate.getMonth(),
        pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
        pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
        pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
        0
);
Date date12_1 = format.parse("1/1/2017");
Lebanon.put(date12_1, "New Year");
if (cal.getTime().compareTo(date12_1) > 0) {
  info.setText(cal.getTime() + "BIGGER THAN     " + date12_1);
} else if (cal.getTime().compareTo(date12_1) == 0) {
  info.setText(cal.getTime() + "EQUAL TO     " + date12_1);
} else if (cal.getTime().compareTo(date12_1) < 0) {
  info.setText(cal.getTime() + "SMALLER THAN     " + date12_1);
}
```

This code works perfectly except for one thing: if `cal.gettime()` is equal to december 1st, it still sais bigger. Output is:

```
Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 EET 2017 BIGGER THAN Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 EET 2017
```

Comment: Obviously you forgot about millis.

Comment: umm..but seconds are 00..what would it matter? @Selvin

Comment: milliseconds are not.. so there is a difference.

Comment: so what doo i do if i want it to say fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 2017 EQUAL to fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 2017, i honestly dont care about seconds and milliseconds and could do without them if possible @Mij

Comment: *honestly dont care about seconds and milliseconds* it doesn't matter .. they **exists** in Calendar object *so what doo i do(...)?* set them both to 0

Comment: how do i do that? and thank you guys for bearing with me @Selvin

Comment: thank you @Selvin that did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set milliseconds in you `cal` object **after** setting time.

```
cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
        pickerDate.getMonth(),
        pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
        pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
        pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
        0
);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

If it will not work, the best way to get right result is to create Calendar object first, then getDate, It's simpler and gives you more options to change. Change your `date12_1` to Calendar object.

```
Date date12_1 = format.parse("1/1/2017"); //change this line
```

to

```
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);    
cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
Date date12_1 = cal2.getTime();
```

Comment: No. This thing only works when the system clock returns the same millisecond in the two calls to `Calendar.getInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

For whole-day events, the best representation in Java 8+ is [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). A `Calendar` is backed by a `long` value and thus is error prone in your case. `LocalDate`, on the other hand, has `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented to suit exactly your use case.

If you absolutely must stick to Java7 and [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is nota a option, consider clearing the Calendar before filling it from your picker:

```
@Test
public void testCalendar() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date(0));

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);

    assertEquals(cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), 0);
}
```

There's even a [`DateUtils.isSameDay`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) in Apache `commons-lang3`.

Comment: not really, equals gives the exact same output. i tried switching my if elses with if(cal.getTime().after(date12_1)){
                        info.setText(cal.getTime() +"BIGGER THAN     "+ date12_1);
                    }else if(cal.getTime().equals(date12_1)){
                       info.setText(cal.getTime() +"EQUAL TO     "+ date12_1);
                    }else if(cal.getTime().before(date12_1)) {
                        info.setText(cal.getTime() +"SMALLER THAN     "+ date12_1);
                    } but no luck...it gives same output

Comment: Yes, really. Don't know what test you are talking about, but the defect is in the test. Also added two options since first writing: 1. clearing the Calendar with `setTime(new Date(0))` and 2. `DateUtils.isSameDay`

Comment: my problem was milliseconds like u said...so thank you it worked now

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getInstance()` also sets the milliseconds retrieved from the system clock.

That means that the milliseconds are almost always greater than 0. I tested it myself, and the timestamps got different values:

```
System.out.println(date12_1.getTime());
System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

You need also to set the milliseconds to 0:

- Either you can set the timestamp to 0 using `setTimeInMillis(0)`
- Or you can set the milliseconds field to 0 using `cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`

Comment: how do i set them to 0 ? @MC Emperor

Comment: You can set it using `setTimeInMillis(0)` *before* setting your time (`cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(), ...`).